# Change title lable on swiping UICollectionView(at some point)

Tags: ios, uilabel, uicollectionview

What should I do ,if I want to change `UILabel`(yearLabel)of screen .I am using `UICollectionView`.When `collectionView` reaches year 2014 I want to change label from 2013 to 2014.
Should I use `BOOL` property.But how?
In `cellForitemAtIndexPath`

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
             cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UICollectionViewCell *myCell = [collectionView
                              dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"

UILabel *yearlabel=(UILabel*)[myCell viewWithTag:1221];
yearlabel.text=[yearArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if [(yearlabel isEqual:@"2014") ] {
        _isLabelChange=YES;
    }
}
return myCell;
```

and my `yearArray` contains data like-

```
 yearArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"2013",@"2013",@"2013",@"2013",@"2013",@"2013",@"2013",@"2013",@"2014",@"2014",@"2014", nil];
```

Comment: Please post your code. There's not much I can do for you blind.

Comment: @cocotutch Please have a look to my edited question

Comment: That should be working, `indexPath.row` will return an object based on the number of cells in the table, and set it. Unless you need to initialise the properties in a `if(cell == nil) {` block to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the label property of `UIcollectionView` and set accordingly.